# Nodejs: get max id from table directly on insert

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to insert a new value in a table (using node.js) and at the same time get the ID to be inserted, using a select MAX from table. First I tried this:

```
var nova = {
    Id: 'Select MAX(Id)+1 from TABELA',
    Id_novo: dados_da_msg[1],
    Nome: dados_da_msg[2],
};
connection.query('INSERT INTO TABELA SET ?', nova, function(err, result) {
    if (err)
        console.log("ERROR23: " + err.message);
});
```

which didn't worked. It always returned 0 and violated the primary key.
Then I tried this

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO TABELA (Id, Id_novo, Nome) Select MAX(Id)+1,'"+dados_da_msg[1]+"','"+dados_da_msg[2]+"' from TABELA;";
connection.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err)
        console.log("ERROR23: " + err.message);
});
```

which worked, but is vulnerable to SQLinjections attacks. Anybody knows how can I achieve this using the first syntax?

Comment: Easy to just downvote. VERY, VERY hard to explain WHY the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your insert result will give something like

```
{ fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 123,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0 }
```

if your id is auto incremental then you'll get the insert id from "insertId".